# In EarthMC (a popular Minecraft Java Edition Server), what are the exact probabilities of getting certain numbers of gold ingots from votecrates?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, earthmc

I really like maths, so I would like to know the exact probabilities so I can work out the average amount of gold ingots received per goldcrate.

Comment: throwing it on google, you can find a wiki saying the chances and the average: https://earthmc.fandom.com/wiki/Crates It says 4 is the average. I didn't investigate further since I'm not familiar with the server and the website lags way too much

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because unless the server publishes these rates, there's no feasible way for us to figure them out. This is a question for the server owners, not Arqade.

Comment: The [site documentation](https://earthmc.net/docs/economy#voting) says: _You will receive a gold crate with a random award of up to 64 gold ingots after successfully voting for the server. [...] The most likely award is 4 gold per vote link._

Comment: @BunnyMerz That’s just an estimate, but I’ll go with that for the time being.

Comment: Voting to leave open. This is on-topic and is answerable.